# Where and how to change the Embedded Login CSS?

Tags: community, css

I want to edit the Embedded Login CSS as is mentioned on the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_replace_css.htm) from documentation:

> Replace the Embedded Login CSS with Your Own Embedded Login comes with a default style sheet, which styles the login button and login
>   form. If you want to replace the default CSS with your own, you have a
>   few options. Use whichever method you prefer.
>
> 1. Override the CSS directly in the web page.
> 2. Edit the Embedded Login CSS. The style sheet is located in your community URL resource folder.
> 3. Replace the style sheet with your own by updating the link on your web page with the location of your style sheet.

And I want to try it with the 2nd point above, but I cannot figure out where is located the style sheet? What does it refer with 'community URL resource folder' ?

Any hints greatly appreciated.